# mongodb failed to launch with mup setup (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, meteor, mup

First i installed UBUNTU 14.04 64bit/32bit (Tried it too with UBUNTU 16.04 64bit).

When i launch `mup setup`, i get this error message:

```
----------------------------------
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setup Docker
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setup Docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setup Environment
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setup Environment
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Copying mongodb.conf
[xx.xx.xx.xx - Copying mongodb.conf: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Start Mongo
[xx.xx.xx.xx] x Start Mongo: FAILED

        -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
        Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var
/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
        Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
        -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I created a username inside the VPS and granted it in order to work without `sudo`, i tried too with root access but all time the same error.

And launched this command before everything inside the VPS: `apt-get update`

Here is my `MUP` version: 1.3.7 (Under Windows 7 64bit)

And here `mup.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
 servers: {
  one: {
      host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
      username: 'myusername',
      password: 'password',
  }
 },
 meteor: {
  name: 'myApp',
  path: '../myApp',
  servers: {
   one: {}
  },
  buildOptions: {
   serverOnly: true
  },
  env: {
   ROOT_URL: 'https://m.domain.com',
   MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
  },
  docker:{
   image: 'abernix/meteord:base'
  },
  deployCheckWaitTime: 96,
  enableUploadProgressBar: false
 },
 mongo: {
  oplog: true,
  port: 27017,
  version: '3.4.1',
  servers: {
   one: {}
  }
 }
};
```

When i try to restart docker from VPS, here the error message:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here the error inside the logs:

```
Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab127.2 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seem to me that you misconfigured the

```
env: {
   ROOT_URL: 'https://m.domain.com',
   MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
},
```

mup create a mongo container and the database is named using the name of your app

```
 env: {
       ROOT_URL: 'https://m.domain.com',
       MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/myapp'
 },
```

And it should work